# Remove archived files

Tags: bash, tar

I need to remove files that older than given in a parameter and add them to the archive with saving the structure.

**file listing**

```
oracle@dbi-702D-6x:~/test.d$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle    0 Sep  6 07:06 aug
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle    0 Feb 10  2015 feb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle    0 Sep  6 07:06 june
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle    0 Mar  3  2015 march
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle    0 Sep  6 07:06 may
drwxrwxr-x 3 oracle oracle 4096 Sep  6 08:00 rem-old-res
-rwxrw-r-- 1 oracle oracle  469 Sep  6 08:00 rem-old.sh
-rwxrw-r-- 1 oracle oracle  467 Sep  6 08:00 rem-old.sh~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle   85 Sep  6 08:00 roll-back.sh
drwxrwxr-x 2 oracle oracle 4096 Sep  6 07:35 some.d

oracle@dbi-702D-6x:~/test.d/some.d$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle 0 Sep  6 07:06 test1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle 0 Sep  6 07:06 test2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 oracle oracle 0 Jan  4  2015 test3
```

**run-on.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname=$2
date=$1
now=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
here=`pwd`

mkdir $HOME/rem-old-res
touch temp-file -d $date 

cp * -R $HOME/rem-old-res
cp -R $HOME/rem-old-res/ $here/rem-old-res

for file in `find rem-old-res -type f -newer temp-file`
do
    rm $file
done

tar czf rem-old-res.tar.gz rem-old-res 

echo "#!/bin/bash" > $here/roll-back.sh
echo "tar xvzf $HOME/rem-old-res.tar.gz $here/rem-old-res" >> $here/roll-back.sh


rm -rf $HOME/rem-old-res
rm $here/temp-file
```

script is called like :

```
./run-on.sh 20150501
```

Feb, march and test3 files are has to be removed by the script, but they don't. I can't get why for loop doesn't work properly.

Comment: post how the script is called ( with parameters )

Comment: @cdarke Sorry, I work all the night, tired a little bit. This is how I call the script ./run-on.sh 20150501. According to the the structure I have in the result I expect to get tar.gz-archive with 3 files: feb, march, some.d/test3. But now I'm getting empty archive with only directory named rem-old-res.

Comment: from the listing, run-on.sh is not in test.d directory

Comment: Check the `man` pages for `touch`.  The `-d` option is about displaying, not setting.  Depending on the version, you probably need `-t` or `-s`.  Check with `ls -l temp-file`

Comment: There are several versions of `touch` and parameter forms vary.  The old default date/time format is not the same as the format you supply.  My version uses `MMDDhhmm[YY]` but yours might be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of my problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

# example of usage ./rem-old.sh 20150501 .
# The first parametr is a date in the format YYMMDD and the second is a path to the particular direcoty 

dirname=$2
date=$1
now=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
here=`pwd`

touch temp-file -d $date 

for file in `find -type f ! -newer temp-file`
do  
    if [[ $file != "./temp-file" ]]
    then
        tar --append --file=rem-old-res.tar $file
        rm $file
    fi
done

gzip rem-old-res.tar

# roll-back.sh is a script to cancel the changes
echo "#!/bin/bash" > $here/roll-back.sh
echo "gzip -d rem-old-res.tar.gz" >> $here/roll-back.sh
echo "tar -xvf rem-old-res.tar" >> $here/roll-back.sh
echo "rm rem-old-res.tar" >> $here/roll-back.sh
chmod u+x roll-back.sh

rm $here/temp-file
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pretty much on a good way, but you did not read the man-pages good enough.

tar has a parameter to remove the files from disk that are added to the archive.

touch uses the -t parameter for setting the file time.

Additionally, you should beware of using variables in bash, see [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) always use quotes

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname=$2
date=$1
now=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
here=`pwd`

touch -t "$date" temp-file
find "$here" -newer temp-file tarfiles 
tar -czf rem-old-res.tar.gz -T tarfiles --remove-files

echo "#!/bin/bash" > $here/roll-back.sh
echo "tar xvzf $HOME/rem-old-res.tar.gz $here/rem-old-res" >> $here/roll-back.sh

rm $here/temp-file
rm $here/tarfiles
```